# GettingPlug in Type' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'custom workflow activity info'

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm working with MS Dynamics CRM 2011 on-premises. I'm unable to register the custom workflow dll with plugin registration tool.

I checked latest roll-up (17). It is still impossible to register custom workflow activity in plugin registration tool.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give description of error you receiving?

Comment: From MSDN, you should build custom workflow dll with .NET Framework 4.
[Create a custom workflow activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx)

Comment: Is this issues fixed? I am also facing the same issue while creating new System Workflow. Please let me know the fix, if you have resolved it.

Comment: what exactly the problem you are facing,  paste the error message here to sort out the problem :)

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive with the question: what are the steps you are taking when you receive this error?  I have registered custom workflow assemblies in most of my CRM 2011 on-premise projects without issue.  Copying and Pasting your C# code would also be helpful to ensure you are implementing the correct classes and have your input and output parameters set up correctly.